# Change default DNS server in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, dns, arch-linux, dhcp

I'm in Viet Nam and most social websites (Facebook, Twitter and the likes - even reddit) are blocked by the ISP DNS server.

I tried to change the DNS server of my Arch box using the `resolv.conf` file, but it failed miserably since `dhcpd` generates this file automatically everytime I connect to the LAN.  I've been looking around to try and find out how to fix this, without success.  Either I s*ck at Googling, either it is non-trivial to do so.

EDIT 1:

Meh, apparently posting it here made me feel guilty and I had to push my search a bit more.  I found the same article than Ankur post below.  This is what I made, if anybody ever faces the same problem:

```
$ sudo gvim /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

Add "nohook resolv.conf" at the tail of the file.

```
$ sudo gvim /etc/resolv.conf
```

Add to the file (OpenDNS servers):

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Or (Google DNS):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Then, verify it worked (need package `dnsutils`):

```
$ dig www.facebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.1-P1 <<>> www.facebook.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16994
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.facebook.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.facebook.com.   89  IN  A   69.171.224.53

;; Query time: 87 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 28 00:43:23 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 61
```

See `;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)`, it worked.

Comment: Consider also using Tor http://torproject.org to bypass censorship and network blocks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resolv.conf#Use_resolv.conf.head) explains: either use a `resolv.conf.head` file, or write-protect `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: this is honestly what _resolv.conf.head_ is designated for. write-protecting _resolv.conf_ doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date; nowadays, best-practice (if using `dhcpd`), is adding the change to `dhcpd`'s configuration *instead*, so the correct `resolv.conf` is generated. (See the linked wikipage; something like `static domain_name_servers=8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8` at the bottom of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.)

Answer (score 7):

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` generally should not be edited by hand. Most linux systems use a program called `resolvconf` that will automatically generate `/etc/resolv.conf` every time you connect to the LAN (as the post describes). Instead, you want to edit the file `/etc/resolvconf.conf`.

Check `man resolvconf` for more information.